# How To Sort Subsets in Java

Tags: java, subset

Dear friends I have an assignment and I almost solved it. But I'm having a big problem recently which I couldn't figure a way out for 2 days. If you could help me I would very appreciate it!

So, let's say user entered 5 **(N)** I immediately create this sequence to get subsets out of it: `{1,2,3,4,5}`

If N = 4 than the sequence is like: `{1, 2, 3, 4}` etc.

Than this code below generates all kind of the variations of subsets:

```
public static int[] genarator(int N)
{
    int[] generator = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, N)];
    int[] binDigit = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, N)];

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, N); i++)
        generator[i] = (i >> 1) ^ i; // Right Shifting

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, N); i++)
    {
        int one = 1;
        binDigit[i] = 0;
        while (generator[i] > 0)
        {
            binDigit[i] += (generator[i] % 2) * one;
            generator[i] /= 2;
            one = one * 10;
        }
    }

    return binDigit;
}
```

And the way it returns the results like this *(In case of: N = 4 {1, 2, 3, 4}) shown here* :

```
1 
1 2 
2 
2 3 
1 2 3 
1 3 
3 
3 4 
1 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 
2 4 
1 2 4 
1 4 
4
```

But my lecturer wants from my program to return the result in this order:

```
1
2
3
4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

I for now use `TreeSet<Long>` and `parseLong` so I can get true results till 1 <= N <= 9. But whenever user enters 10 or higher as N it goes crazy.

**To recap, my question is** how can I store those numbers which I get from `int[] genarator(int N)` and display them like my lecturer requires ?

*How generator works and how do I get numbers in wrong order?* Code is below:

```
int N = read.nextInt();

        int[] sequence = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            sequence[i] = i + 1;

        int[] tempArray = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, N)];
        tempArray = genarator(N);

        for (int i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, N); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (tempArray[i] % 10 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print(sequence[j] + " ");
                }
                tempArray[i] /= 10;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

*Thank you for checking and I am really sorry for this too long question. But I couldn't make it clear with a short explanation.*

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a set abstraction that can be compared to other sets.  See Java tutorials on [Comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

```
    //don't call this Set as there is already a Java Set 
    //interface that youdon't want to confuse yourself with   
    public class MySet implements Comparable<MySet>{

        int[] backingArray;

        public MySet(int n) {
           //initialize the Set
           this.backingArray = generator(n);
        }

        public static Int[] generator(int n) {
            //..whatever you do to generate your results
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MySet otherSet) {
           //define how sets are compared (e.g what your professor is asking.  
           //In your example, if one set is shorter than another, 
           //it is considered 'smaller')
        }

    }

Set<MySet> allSets = ....;
```

and simply invoke `Collections.sort(allSets);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now I am trying to improve my code as you shown above and checking the link you shared about comparators. But I'm afraid comparing each subsets and sorting them using this way will cross with time-limit.

Comment: Unfortunately generator doesn't seem to work properly with this way. Prompting many issues. I assume that It requires a different approach to algorithm. Is there any other way depending on my current output to sort them? Or is it possible to implement this solution to the current output ?